# mpdf displays ascii<115 incorrectly

Tags: apache, character-encoding, fonts, pdf-generation, mpdf

Up until recently, mpdf was working fine for me. Now it seems to be unable to display symbols with ascii values less than 115 (letter s). My sysadmin cannot recall any major changes to the system. I have not made any changes to my code. Here is a test script that reproduces the issue:

```
<?php //PHP 5.4.15

include('/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/mpdf/mpdf.php'); // mpdf 5.6 (and previously 5.5), apache 2.4

$good='stuvwxyz{}|'; //ascii >=115
$bad='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqr';

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->WriteHTML("$bad <br> $good"); //note that <br> renders just fine
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

produces this output:

[image: incorrect characters]

I think this must be a font issue. But I'm using the default embedded mpdf fonts (DejaVu). Any ideas why this might be happening?

No errors:

- mpdf throws no errors, even with debug on
- apache error log has nothing

### ETA 1:

Running the above script from the **command line** produces a valid and readable pdf file. The php and mpdf versions being used are the same. **The problem only occurs when run from a browser** (FF, IE, Chrome were tested). Problem files are unreadable with Acrobat Reader, Ghostwriter and Evince.

### ETA 2:

We've localized the problem to our production Apache 2.4 server.  Our dev server (minimal install) outputs the test script without difficulty.

These are the modules running on our production server:

```
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
LoadModule security2_module modules/mod_security2.so
```

### ETA some analysis of the output file:

```
% python pdfid.py mpdf.pdf

PDFiD 0.0.12 mpdf.pdf
PDF Header: %PDF-1.4
obj                   13
endobj                13
stream                 4
endstream              4
xref                   1
trailer                1
startxref              1
/Page                  1
/Encrypt               0
/ObjStm                0
/JS                    0
/JavaScript            0
/AA                    0
/OpenAction            1
/AcroForm              0
/JBIG2Decode           0
/RichMedia             0
/Launch                0
/EmbeddedFile          0
/Colors > 2^24         0


% python pdf-parser.py mpdf.pdf

PDF Comment '%PDF-1.4\n'

PDF Comment '%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\n'

obj 3 0
Type: /Page
Referencing: 1 0 R, 2 0 R, 4 0 R

<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
/TrimBox [0.000 0.000 595.280 841.890]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Group
<<
/Type /Group
/S /Transparency
/CS /DeviceRGB
>>
/Contents 4 0 R
>>


obj 4 0
Type:
Referencing:
Contains stream

<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 132
>>


obj 1 0
Type: /Pages
Referencing: 3 0 R

<<
/Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R ]
/Count 1
/MediaBox [0 0 595.280 841.890]
>>


obj 5 0
Type: /Font
Referencing: 6 0 R, 7 0 R

<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type0
/BaseFont /MPDFAA+DejaVuSerifCondensed
/Encoding /Identity-H
/DescendantFonts [6 0 R]
/ToUnicode 7 0 R
>>


obj 6 0
Type: /Font
Referencing: 8 0 R, 9 0 R, 10 0 R

<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /CIDFontType2
/BaseFont /MPDFAA+DejaVuSerifCondensed
/CIDSystemInfo 8 0 R
/FontDescriptor 9 0 R
/DW 540
/W [ 32 [ 286 361 414 754 572 855 801 247 351 351 450 754 286 304 286 303 ]
48 57 572 58 59 303 60 62 754 63 [ 482 900 650 661 688 721 657 624 719 785 355 360 672 598 921 787 738 605 738 677 616 600 758 650 925 641 594 625 351 303 351 754 450 450 536 576 504 576 532 333 576 580 288 279 545 288 853 580 542 576 576 430 461 361 580 508 770 507 508 474 572 303 572 754 ]
]
/CIDToGIDMap 10 0 R
>>


obj 7 0
Type:
Referencing:
Contains stream

<<
/Length 345
>>


obj 8 0
Type:
Referencing:

<<
/Registry (Adobe)
/Ordering (UCS)
/Supplement 0
>>


obj 9 0
Type: /FontDescriptor
Referencing: 11 0 R

<<
/Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /MPDFAA+DejaVuSerifCondensed
/Ascent 928
/Descent -236
/CapHeight 928
/Flags 4
/FontBBox [-693 -347 1512 1242]
/ItalicAngle 0
/StemV 87
/MissingWidth 540
/Style
<<
/Panose <0 0 2 6 6 6 5 6 5 2 2 4>
>>
/FontFile2 11 0 R
>>


obj 10 0
Type:
Referencing:
Contains stream

<<
/Length 302
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>


obj 11 0
Type:
Referencing:
Contains stream

<<
/Length 11270
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length1 19752
>>


obj 2 0
Type:
Referencing: 5 0 R

<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font
<<
/F1 5 0 R
>>
>>


obj 12 0
Type:
Referencing:

<<
/Producer (\ufffd\ufffd)
/CreationDate (20130610101337-03'00')
/ModDate (20130610101337-03'00')
>>


obj 13 0
Type: /Catalog
Referencing: 1 0 R, 3 0 R

<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
/OpenAction [3 0 R /XYZ null null 1]
/PageLayout /OneColumn
>>


xref

trailer
<<
/Size 14
/Root 130R
/Info 120R
/ID [<7e16ee374f9301bc714ec37fbcaf2e35><7e16ee374f9301bc714ec37fbcaf2e35>]
>>

startxref 14000

PDF Comment '%%EOF'
```

Answer (score 0):

We still have not figured out the issue, but it can be circumvented by only using core fonts.  To do this call mPDF this way:

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c');
```

I hope this is helpful to someone else afflicted with this weird problem.